# Align Pandas barchart style

Tags: pandas, dataframe, alignment, bar-chart

please I went through the documentation on:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html
section "Bar Charts" but when I try to use the same code with this simple dataframe it seems something is going wrong.
My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,19],[0,-3,16],[1,0,21]], columns = ["5D Net Chg","20D Net Chg","60D Net Chg"] )
df.style.bar(subset=["5D Net Chg","20D Net Chg","60D Net Chg"], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

If you run this code, you should see what I see, that is:
* the -3 cell is fully red, whereas I would expect to see a red bar starting from the middle of the cell
* the cell with value 1 is fully green. I would expect to see a tiny green bar starting from the middle of the cell, given the max value in the dataframe is 21

what could I do to make it look like more like the "Conditional Formatting" data bars we have in excel?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to align the value `0` in the mid of the cell. So you should choose `align='zero'`. Note that the aligning works columnwise.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,-5],[0,-3,16],[1,2,21]], columns = [1,2,3] )
df.style.bar(subset=[1,2,3], align='zero', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is correct. It's just the values that you have. Changing the values to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,2,19],[0,-3,16],[1,-4,21]], 
columns = ["5D Net Chg","20D Net Chg","60D Net Chg"] )
```

I obtain this

`df.style.bar(subset=["5D Net Chg","20D Net Chg","60D Net Chg"], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])`

[image]